# Facebook Graph API - Friend's Birthday with year?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api with friends_birthday permission.

I am getting month and date only.
How to get the year?

Thanks

Comment: You can get the current year with PHP, why you need to return this with Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information returned is based off that user's privacy settings.  If the user has allowed it to be displayed to friends, then you will receive the year.  Otherwise, only the information you can retrieve is what is permitted.  For example, if you look at some user's profiles, you will notice that the only portion of the birthday displayed is month and day.  If this is the case, then the year would not be returned as that user has not given Facebook permission to make that information available.  There is no way around this.

Comment: how can i get only those friends who is showing their birth year?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to simply request that Facebook only returns users with their birth year visible.  The best approach I could suggest would be testing to see if the birth year is present, if so, adding that user's information to your own array and ignoring it if not.  If you step through all possibilities, you will end with only an array containing user's that display their birth year.

Comment: I have the same problem... The thing is when I go on the profile of these friends it shows their full birthday data. However, when I request it via the graph api (of FQL) I get either an empty string, or  only month/day. Any ideas what security setting effect this?